# Barcode in CPCL ( Zebra Printer)

Tags: java, android, zebra-printers

I'm having trouble..

I 'm needing to print a bar code on the `CPCL` Zebra printer language, however I am not getting success.

I have the following code to print a code bars

```
builder.append("B I2OF5 1 2 120 43 59 123456");
```

however , it is not printing ...

checking the printer documentation , have the following documentation :

[image]

note :

placing the code to another type of bar code ( e.g. 128 ) works ..

Thank you for your attention .. sorry for my English

Comment: I don't know the CPCL as such, but from the documentation it seems like your parameters don't fit: you have type=0, but it should be one of the type symbols (UPCA, EAN132, 93, 128 etc). The width seems small, the ratio=120 is not covered in the docu (max seems to be 30?)

Comment: sorry , I put the wrong command here!
already I edited the post ..

Comment: my guess would be that there are special restrictions for this type of barcode, a special ratio or width/height correlation that has to match